# Split string to array with ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, split

I have the string: `"how to \"split string\" to \"following array\""` (*how to "split string" to "following array"*).

I want to get the following array:

```
["how", "to", "split string", "to", "following array"]
```

I tried `split(' ')` but the result is:

```
["how", "to", "\"split", "string\"", "to", "\"following", "array\""]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x.split('"').reject(&:empty?).flat_map do |y|
  y.start_with?(' ') || y.end_with?(' ') ? y.split : y
end
```

Explanation:

- `split('"')` will partition the string in a way that non-quoted strings will have a leading or trailing space and the quoted ones wouldn't.
- The following `flat_map` will further split an individual string by space only if it falls in the non-quoted category.
- Note that if there are two consecutive quoted strings, the space in between will be it's own string after the first space and will completely disappear after the second. Aka:

  ```
  'foo "bar" "baz"'.split('"') # => ["foo ", "bar", " ", "baz"]
  ' '.split # => []
  ```
- The `reject(&:empty?)` is needed in case we start with a quoted string as

  ```
  '"foo"'.split('"') # => ["", "foo"]
  ```

Answer (score 0):

With `x` as your string:

`x.split(?").each_slice(2).flat_map{|n, q| a = n.split; (a << q if q) || a }`

When you split on quotes, you know for certain that each string in the array goes: non-quoted, quoted, non-quoted, quoted, non-quoted etc...

If we group these into pairs then we get one of the following two scenarios:

1. `[ "non-quoted", "quoted" ]`
2. `[ "non-quoted", nil ]` (only ever for the last pair of an unbalanced string)

For example 1, we split nq and append q
For example 2, we split nq and discard q
i.e.: `a = n.split; (a << q if q) || q`

Then we join all the pairs back up (the flat part of `flat_map`)